# Compiler error : 'area' not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I've just started learning c++ and am trying to write a program for finding the area of a circle. I've written the program and whenever I try to compile it I get 2 error messages. The first is:

```
areaofcircle.cpp:9:14: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
```

and the second is:

```
areaofcircle.cpp:18:5: error: 'area' was not declared in this scope
```

What should I do? I would post a picture, but I'm a new user, so I can't.

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
#define pi 3.1415926535897932384626433832795 
int main() 
{
    // Create three float variable values: r, pi, area 
    float r, pi, area; 
    cout << "This program computes the area of a circle." << endl; 

    // Prompt user to enter the radius of the circle, read input value into variable r 
    cout << "Enter the radius of the circle " << endl; 
    cin >> r; 

    // Square r and then multiply by pi area = r * r * pi; 
    cout << "The area is " << area << "." << endl; 
}
```

Comment: And, where is the program? post it here. Copy the text, not a picture.

Comment: Please post a code example that shows your error. We promise not to steal it :-)

Comment: How about posting code? Do you understand what the errors mean?

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out. I had essentially defined pi twice.

Comment: You can edit the post...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is relatively simple. See below.

> ```
> #define pi 3.1415926535897932384626433832795 
> int main() 
> {
>     // Create three float variable values: r, pi, area 
>     float r, pi, area; 
> ...
> ```

Notice you use a macro expansion for `pi`. This replaces the variable name `pi` in your declaration with the text `3.1415926535897932384626433832795`. This causes the error seen here:

> error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

Now, since this caused parsing to fail on that statement, `area` winds up never being declared (since it's after `pi`). As a result, you also then recieve the following error:

> error: 'area' was not declared in this scope

Note that you also actually assign neither `pi` nor `area`... you need to do that first.

As a general rule of thumb, *don't use macros for constants in C++*.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
  using std::cin;
  using std::cout;
  using std::endl;
  using std::atan;

  cout << "This program computes the area of a circle." << endl;

  cout << "Enter the radius of the circle " << endl;
  float r;
  cin >> r;

  float pi = acos(-1.0f);
  float area = 2 * pi * r;
  cout << "The area is " << area << '.' << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Another good tip - use `clang` instead of `gcc` and get better error messages that actually explain what's going on in much more detail (and in colour!).

Comment: @CarlNorum haha woops, I was looking at the errors from another post a second ago and my mind slipped... you're right... :-p

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you never actually assign anything to 'area', so it remains undefined (effectively contains a random number). Try adding the line `area = r * r * pi;` before the last cout. You also want to remove the `float pi` from the variable list since it collides with the `#define pi` at the top.  Later, when you learn about `#include <math>` you *may* find an `M_PI` constant inside so that you don't have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Modified code that builds and works fine :

```
///--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------!
// file:    Area.cpp
//
// summary: console program for SO

#include <iostream> 

using namespace std; 

const double PI = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795;


int main() 
{
    // Create three float variable values: r, pi, area 
    double r, area; 
    cout << "This program computes the area of a circle." << endl; 

    // Prompt user to enter the radius of the circle, read input value into variable r 
    cout << "Enter the radius of the circle " << endl; 
    cin >> r; 

    // Square r and then multiply by pi area = r * r * pi; 
    area = PI*r*r;
    cout << "The area is " << area << "." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```